# Is there any stockfish web api?

Tags: engines, stockfish, websites

I would like to create a web page with a stockfish analysis which evaluates the sharpness of position, but to do that I would like to avoid to upload myself a Stockfish program in the cloud. I would like to have a web API which would give me back the eval of a certain position. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well, Stockfish is open-source so what people do generally is they put the engine to the frontend and let it run locally on each user. That way your server does not overload with the computations.

Comment: yeah, I guess I'll have to do it that way. Do you have any estimates about how much could it cost per user? I would like to make the project free but worried that it will cost me too much.

Comment: The engine does not cost **you** (server) in this way, but the computation depth depends on the computational power of the individual users, because you use their computer in a sense. Today's average computer is usually enough to get a decent analysis.

Comment: ah, interesting, so I can let the user take charge of the engine computation. Ok, thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js/